# Nonlinear LAD regression in R

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I would like to estimate the parameters of a nonlinear regression model with LAD regression. In essence the LAD estimator is an M-estimator. As far as I know it is not possible to use the `robustbase` package to do this. How could I use R to do LAD regression? Could I use a standard package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with the built-in `optim()` function

Make up some data (make sure `x` is positive, so that `a*x^b` makes sense - raising negative numbers to fractional powers is problematic):

```
set.seed(101)
a <- 1; b <- 2
dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000,mean=7))
dd$y <- a*dd$x^b + rnorm(1000,mean=0,sd=0.1)
```

Define objective function:

```
objfun <- function(p) {
  pred <- p[1]*dd$x^p[2]   ## a*x^b
  sum(abs(pred-dd$y))      ## least-absolute-deviation criterion
}
```

Test objective function:

```
objfun(c(0,0))
objfun(c(-1,-1))
objfun(c(1,2))
```

Optimize:

```
o1 <- optim(fn=objfun, par=c(0,0), hessian=TRUE)
```

You do need to specify starting values, and deal with any numerical/computational issues yourself ...

I'm not sure I know how to compute standard errors: you can use `sqrt(diag(solve(o1$hessian)))`, but I don't know if the standard theory on which this is based still applies ...

Comment: Thank You. Do you think that `nlrq(formula, data=parent.frame(), start, tau=0.5, 
        control, trace=FALSE,method="L-BFGS-B")` (`quantreg` package) does the trick as well?

Comment: using `nlrq` seems reasonable.